# Is there any function for merge objects having same key

Tags: dictionary, object, merge, concatenation, assign

I got response like

```
[
    {
      "userid": 1,
      "Jun": 1
    },
    {
      "userid": 2,
      "Jun": 2
    },
    {
      "userid": 2,
      "Jul": 5
    },
    {
      "userid": 2,
      "Jan": 1
    }
]
```

But I want response like

```
[
    {"userid": 1, "Jun": 1},
    {"userid": 2, "Jun": 1, "Jul": 5}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

response = [
    {"userid": 1, "Jun": 1},
    {"userid": 2, "Jun": 2},
    {"userid": 2, "Jul": 5},
    {"userid": 2, "Jan": 1},
]

result = defaultdict(dict)
for r in response:
    result[r["userid"]].update(**r)

response = list(result.values())

print(response)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'userid': 1, 'Jun': 1}, {'userid': 2, 'Jun': 2, 'Jul': 5, 'Jan': 1}]
```